# discord bot set game status with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

how can i change my bots game status. i tried this code but didnt work :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('discord-reply');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const ayarlar = require('./ayarlar.json')

var prefix = ayarlar.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Bot ${client.user.tag} başlatıldı...`);
  //client.channels.cache.get('832756476379922462').send('Bot başlatıldı')
  client.user.setGame('bhelp ')
});
```

Error :
[PowerShell Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2RXr.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error said, `ClientUser#setGame()` is not a function. Instead, use [`ClientUser#setActivity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) or [`ClientUser#setPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence).

```js
client.user.setActivity('bhelp');
```